# Most reasonable solution to encrypting my paypal API credentials?

Tags: c#, encryption, paypal, e-commerce

I understand that i'm never going to be completely safe ... but paypal documentation seems to stress that I should never plain-text store the API credentials in my code (ie, web.config or in some C#).

1) What is a reasonable way to protect it... without going OVERBOARD?
2) If I encrypt the keys in my web.config... where do I store the encryption key... in the database, right? But then... the connection strings to my database are also visible in the web.config... so I don't understand why this is considered safety...

My website is an ecommerce store and will probably be on Arvixe business shared server.

Comment: I have one more question... please see comments to the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would encrypt the Paypal credentials and store this encrypted information in the web.config. Do the decryption in a separate DLL and obfuscate this DLL. You could also protect this DLL with an external protection system but we have had issues in the past where protected libraries don't always work correctly in shared web environments.

Comment: so the encryption/decryption key should be store in the DLL also?

Comment: one more followupquestion -- I just downloaded Eazfuscator.net to obfuscate my dll.  I see it has a built in feature to obfuscate... and to DEOBFUSCATE. What prevents a malicious hacker from just taking my obfucated dll and de-ofuscating it to get my encryption key?

Comment: It will be extremely difficult for them to get to your DLL. If they can get access to your web site then there is nothing preventing them from modifying the code to accept deposits into another account or using it to steal credit cards. You can do some basic encryption of the decryption key in the DLL as well but if they get access to your libraries then that is the least of your concerns. If you are really concerned, you can use an off the shelf protection system to encrypt and lock down the obfuscated DLL and then test it with your hosting company.

Comment: thanks gray, I guess your right.  It seems what you proposed above is the "reasonable" solution without going too overboard...